# TestNG skips subsequent runs of @Test(invocationCount = 3) if @AfterMethod fails

Tags: java, testng

Running this code with testNG:

```
package org.example;

import org.testng.annotations.AfterMethod;
import org.testng.annotations.BeforeMethod;
import org.testng.annotations.Test;

public class Test1 {

    @BeforeMethod(alwaysRun = true)
    public void before() throws Exception {
        System.out.println("BEFORE, thread ID=" + Thread.currentThread().getId());
    }

    @AfterMethod(alwaysRun = true)
    public void after() throws Exception {
        System.out.println("AFTER, thread ID=" + Thread.currentThread().getId());
        throw new Exception("Error!");
    }

    @Test(alwaysRun = true, invocationCount = 3, threadPoolSize = 1)
    public void test() throws Exception {
        System.out.println("TEST, thread ID=" + Thread.currentThread().getId());
    }

}
```

returns

```
BEFORE, thread ID=1
TEST, thread ID=1
AFTER, thread ID=1
BEFORE, thread ID=1
AFTER, thread ID=1
BEFORE, thread ID=1
AFTER, thread ID=1
```

The @Test method is being run only 1st time and skipped afterwards. How to achieve this instead, i.e. avoid skipping the @Test method:

```
BEFORE, thread ID=1
TEST, thread ID=1
AFTER, thread ID=1
BEFORE, thread ID=1
TEST, thread ID=1
AFTER, thread ID=1
BEFORE, thread ID=1
TEST, thread ID=1
AFTER, thread ID=1
```

Answer (score 0):

The result shows that the tests are running in sequence, and not in prallel.
Therefore, a single thread is being used for running all the 3 invocations of the test case.

If the invocations need to be run in parallel, then the following parameters must be set in the testng.xml file:

1. parallel="methods"
2. thread-count="3"

A working example testng.xml file for parallel runs:

```
<suite name="Run tests in parallel" parallel="methods" thread-count="3">
    <test name="3-threads-in-parallel">
        <classes>
            <class name="com.company.tests.TestClass"/>
        </classes>
    </test>
</suite>
```

Comment: No, I do explicitly NOT want to run in parallel because test communicates with a device via serial port. The sequence is good, what matters is the absence of `test()` invocation in 2nd & 3rd run.

Comment: The result shows that the test had actually run 3 times. One thread at a time. The thread ID of '1' being printed 3 times shows that the test ran 3 times on thread # 1 only.

Comment: Have a closer look at my initial post: @Test method run 1st time only. I would like to have it run 3 times instead.